# How to avoid running over a large table multiple times in MySQL using subqueries?

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, subquery

I have a products table in `MySQL 5..0.88/Coldfusion8` on a site I inherited.

I need to query the table multiple times to fill default values in a search form and do the actual search.

All my queries are basically the same and eat a lot of time. The only thing changing is the parameter being queried for, the actual query setup doesn't change, so I'm hoping this is possible to somehow bundle in a single query to avoid running query x to get value A, then running query x to get value B and so on....

My dumped query looks like this:

```
 // 1/6 queries - get all company names based on active products
 SELECT art.firma
      FROM artikelstammdaten AS art USE INDEX (i_firma)
      // join pricelists to exclude seller if pricelists applicable but user not authorized 
      LEFT JOIN preislisten p ON 
           p.iln = art.iln
           AND p.ean = art.ean 
           // dynamic list of seller IDs and pricelist name
           AND ( (  p.preisliste = "name1" AND p.iln= "12345" ) OR (  p.preisliste = "name2" AND p.iln= "98765" ) OR (1=0) )

            WHERE art.aktiv = "ja" 
            // if pricelists apply, only take products with a pice not zero
            AND ( IF( art.iln IN ( 12345,98765), p.preisliste IS NOT NULL,1 ) )
            // exclude demo
            AND art.iln != "111" AND art.iln != "222" AND art.iln != "777"
            // sellers free to order or authorization ok
            AND (art.modus = "OPEN" OR art.iln IN ( 12345,98765) )
            // inventory
            AND ( art.bestand != "0" ) AND art.vororder = "0"
            // order mode
            AND ( art.vororder = 'nein' OR art.vororder = 'no' )
            GROUP BY art.firma
```

After this runs, I'm having to run it again to get:

```
 art.marke= brandnames
 art.preis_aktuell = minimum buying price
 art.preis_vk = maximum buying price
 ... 4 more
```

I have been trying to do this using subqueries like so:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
      ( SELECT art.firma  ) AS firma
     ,( SELECT art.marke  ) AS marke
     ,( SELECT MIN(art.preis_aktuell) ) AS ak_min
     ,( SELECT MAX(art.preis_aktuell) ) AS ak_max
     ,( SELECT MIN(art.preis_vk) ) AS vk_min
     ,( SELECT MAX(art.preis_vk) ) AS vk_max
     ,( SELECT ROUND(MIN( 100*( ( art.preis_ek - art.preis_aktuell ) / art.preis_ek ) ))) AS reb_min
     ,( SELECT ROUND(MAX( 100*( ( art.preis_ek - art.preis_aktuell ) / art.preis_ek ) ))) AS reb_max
 FROM artikelstammdaten AS art USE INDEX (i_iln,)
    ....
    GROUP BY art.marke
    ORDER BY COUNT(art.marke) DESC;
```

But I can't get it to work, because I'm only getting a single record (ok for min/max values, but not for x-sellers, y-brands and 20 sizes. I figure this is due to me not knowing how to group subquerys, so:

**Question:**
Is it possible to `bundle` the above queries into a single query using subqueries/some other means? How would I have to `GROUP BY` so I'm not ending up with a single result record?

Thanks for helping out!

**EDIT:**
Maybe have it. Changed to `SELECT DISTINCT` and `GROUPB BY` (see above). Question now is how to order the specific columns and if the result is valid (checking this now)

**EDIT2:**
Here is the create for both tables `"Articles"` and `"Pricelists"`. Articles include basic product including base price, pricelists contains alternative prices, which can be assigned to a user.

**Articles CREATE (fields are in German, I converted above query back to German)**

```
CREATE TABLE `articles` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `iln` VARCHAR(13) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `ean` VARCHAR(35) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `artikelnummer` VARCHAR(35) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `artikelbezeichnung` VARCHAR(70) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `artikelbezeichnung_lang` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `groesse` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `farbe` VARCHAR(35) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `farbnummer` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `material` VARCHAR(70) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `preis_ek` DECIMAL(12,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `preis_vk` DECIMAL(12,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `preis_aktuell` DECIMAL(12,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `einheit` VARCHAR(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `firma` VARCHAR(35) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `marke` VARCHAR(35) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `warengruppe1` VARCHAR(35) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `warengruppe2` VARCHAR(35) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `warengruppe3` VARCHAR(35) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `groessenlauf` VARCHAR(35) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `bildpfad` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `bilddateiname` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `nos` VARCHAR(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `nos_anzeige` VARCHAR(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `aktiv` VARCHAR(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `vororder` VARCHAR(4) NULL DEFAULT 'Nein',
    `highlight` VARCHAR(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `modus` VARCHAR(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `bestand` DECIMAL(10,0) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `last_import` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `last_update` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `i_iln` (`iln`),
    INDEX `i_iln_id` (`id`, `iln`),
    INDEX `i_aktiv` (`aktiv`),
    INDEX `i_bestand` (`bestand`),
    INDEX `i_artikelnummer` (`artikelnummer`),
    INDEX `i_artikelbezeichnung` (`artikelbezeichnung`),
    INDEX `i_artikelbezeichnung_lang` (`artikelbezeichnung_lang`),
    INDEX `i_farbe` (`farbe`),
    INDEX `i_groesse` (`groesse`),
    INDEX `i_preis_aktuell` (`preis_aktuell`),
    INDEX `i_preis_vk` (`preis_vk`),
    INDEX `i_warengruppe1` (`warengruppe1`),
    INDEX `i_warengruppe2` (`warengruppe2`),
    INDEX `i_nos` (`nos`),
    INDEX `i_modus` (`modus`),
    INDEX `i_firma` (`firma`),
    INDEX `i_marke` (`marke`),
    INDEX `i_highlight` (`highlight`),
    INDEX `i_preis_ek` (`preis_ek`),
    INDEX `i_warengruppe3` (`warengruppe3`),
    INDEX `i_farbnummer` (`farbnummer`),
    INDEX `i_ean` (`ean`),
    INDEX `i_vororder` (`vororder`)        
    )
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

**pricelist table CREATE**

```
CREATE TABLE `preislisten` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `iln` VARCHAR(13) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `preisliste` VARCHAR(35) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `bezeichnung` VARCHAR(35) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `EAN` VARCHAR(14) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `waehrung` VARCHAR(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `ek` DECIMAL(18,3) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `vk` DECIMAL(18,3) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `onlinepreis` DECIMAL(18,3) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `i_iln` (`iln`),
    INDEX `ind_onlinepreis` (`onlinepreis`)
    )
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

**SELECT**

```
SELECT DISTINCT
     ( SELECT art.firma  ) AS comp
    ,( SELECT art.marke  ) AS marke
    ,( SELECT MIN(art.preis_aktuell) ) AS ak_min
    ,( SELECT MAX(art.preis_aktuell) ) AS ak_max
    ,( SELECT MIN(art.preis_vk) ) AS vk_min
    ,( SELECT MAX(art.preis_vk) ) AS vk_max
    ,( SELECT ROUND(MIN( 100*( ( art.preis_ek - art.preis_aktuell ) / art.preis_ek ) ))) AS reb_min
    ,( SELECT ROUND(MAX( 100*( ( art.preis_ek - art.preis_aktuell ) / art.preis_ek ) ))) AS reb_max     

    FROM artikelstammdaten AS art USE INDEX (i_
    LEFT JOIN preislisten p ON 
                p.iln = art.iln 
            AND p.ean = art.ean 
            AND ( (  p.preisliste = "-Standard-" AND p.iln = "9900000003005" ) OR (  p.preisliste = "-Standard-" AND p.iln = "2222222222222" ) OR (1=0) )

            WHERE art.aktiv = "ja" 
            AND ( IF( art.iln IN ( 9900000003005,2222222222222 ), p.onlinepreis IS NOT NULL,1 ) )
            AND art.iln != "1111111111111" AND art.iln != "2222222222222" AND art.iln != "7777777777777"
            AND (art.modus = "OPEN" 
                    OR art.iln IN ( 9900000003005,2222222222222 ) 
            )
            AND ( art.bestand != "0" OR ( ( art.nos = "JA" OR art.nos = "YES" ) AND art.nos_anzeige = "JA" ) )  AND art.vororder = "nein"
            AND ( art.vororder = 'nein' OR art.vororder = 'no' )
```

**EXPLAIN SELECT**

```
"id "select_type"   "table" "type"  "possible_keys" "key"   "key_len"   "ref"   "rows"  "Extra"
"1" "SIMPLE"    "art"   "ref"   "i_iln,i_aktiv,i_bestand,i_nos,i_modus,i_vororder"  "i_aktiv"   "7" "const" "16844" "Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort"
"1" "SIMPLE"    "p" "ref"   "i_iln" "i_iln" "16"    "db.art.iln"    "1075"  "Using where"
```

Ok. A lot of data... let me know if you have any questions. The indeces on `articles` seem a bit much. The time killer is the LEFT JOIN with pricelists. Without this, the query is pretty quick, but this is seldomly the case.

Thanks for taking a look! I would bounty this, if anyone can give me a good answer on how to speed this up!

**EDIT 3**:
I added the `Unique index`. Re-running the query now `EXPLAIN` is:

```
"id" "select_type"  "table" "type"  "possible_keys" "key"   "key_len"   "ref"   "rows"  "Extra"
"1"  "SIMPLE"        "art"  "ref"   "i_iln,i_aktiv,i_bestand,i_nos,i_modus,i_vororder"  "i_aktiv"   "7" "const" "15409" "Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort"
"1"  "SIMPLE"        "p"    "ref"   "i_iln_ean,i_iln"   "i_iln_ean" "33"    "db.art.iln,db.art.ean" "1" "Using where"
```

Seems a little faster. The execution time is down to 0, so I guess this is a good sign :-). Question: should I also add this index to the articles table. It will be unique there as well.

Comment: Wait, before merging these 4 slow queries into 1 superquery... which you 'hope' will be faster but most likely will be even slower: why not just speed up the query as is? Can you post an `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` together with your `SHOW CREATE TABLE`?

Comment: Ok. 1sec. Actually it's two tables = articles and priceslists. Give me a few mins

Comment: No, your edit will not work. It will give you the `DISTINCT` *combination* of the values listed, not the distinct of each one.

Comment: mh. ok. Posting create and explain. 1 sec

Comment: Can you post the explain for the query at the top? The one with the subqueries is completely wrong.

Comment: Create an index `(iln, ean)` for `preislisten` - and if you could make it unique that would help even more. A combo index with both columns in the same index. Get rid of `USE INDEX (i_firma)` and instead run `ANALYZE TABLE preislisten`.

Comment: Ok combo index. How do make it unique?

Comment: Just say `UNIQUE INDEX (...)` but make sure it really is unique for those values. Why are you joining that table? Do you actually need fields from there, or are you checking for existence of a price record? Because if so, then using `EXISTS` and not joining would probably help you.

Comment: A seller can assign a pricelist to a user. if that happens (usually), I need to grab the pricelist_prices and currency of all items that have a price (that's why I'm excluding `onlinepreis != 0`. This easily allows to modify assortments by pricelist/user (no price no show). So yes, I need to grab values from there. Checking Èxists` though. The index will be unique, because ILN/EAN combinations will be unique.

Comment: The unique composite index should help a lot. After you do it post the updated explain.

Comment: Ok. I will repost, what's happening. Big Thanks so far!

Comment: I did not get your question properly which two queries you want two merge? different group by for 6 combinations?

Comment: @Omesh: oh. I should have said tables, not queries. I have two tables I need to merge and I need to run this `merged-table-query` multiple times. This was my original question: can I avoid running it multiple times by using a subquery or other means

Comment: This: `INDEX `i_iln_id` (`id`, `iln`)` is useless - id is unique, no point in pairing it this way. Make an index on `(iln, ean)` for `articles` as well, unique if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `GROUP BY art.comp` I assume what you really mean to do is `SELECT DISTINCT`?

Anyway, if you think about it the various columns you are getting all return a different number of rows, since you don't know how many distinct values each will have.

This automatically tells you that you can not return them all at once as columns: How many rows would you get?

If the query is slow then you should work on that - I see nothing there that should make a query slow. You probably need some composite indexes for your tables so MySQL can filter things better.

Comment: mh. you are right about the different no of records I'm expecting back. So I can at least combine the queries that return a single record (value), which are all the price/queries. Still this thing is slow...

Comment: ok. I have set up unique indices for both tables. I'm still running the Query 4 times (companies, brands, min-max, sizes), but if I dump the queries, they are all 0ms now, which looks good to me for now. I will test some and see how it works out. Will repost.